# Deleting Records in SQL using a DELETE query

Tags: sql

Below is the query I have which returns results that I want to delete from a table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

How do I go about deleting the records that show up from this query? I was thinking of using this `DELETE` query.

```
DELETE FROM tableA
WHERE 
     (SELECT * 
      FROM tableA
      GROUP BY id
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 5)
```

But this does not seem to be working.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in`:

```
delete from tableA
where id in (select id from tableA group by id having count(*) > 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this sort of situation, you probably need to do something like this:

```
DELETE from tableA
where [id] IN
(SELECT [id] from tableA
group by id
having count(*) > 5)
```